# tar: Failed to open '/dev/sa0' error in FreeBSD

Tags: bash, freebsd, tar

I have a bash code below under FreeBSD:

```
tar -c file1 > file1.tar
```

It gives below error when I run it. Do you know how can I fix it?

```
tar: Failed to open '/dev/sa0'
```

Comment: You don't specify your archive file here, and on FreeBSD it appears that `/dev/sa0` is the default. Is this what you want? Do you have such a device?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suggest passing `-f -` to `tar` (in addition of the other arguments) to indicate that the tar file you want to create is the *stdout* stream.

```
tar -f - -c file1 > file1.tar
```